# Python KivyMD - input from one screen, display output in another screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to make a 2 page Kivy app - input a word, output definition on another screen. I tried Kivy, it worked. Now I used KivyMD. I encountered NameError.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Andrew/PycharmProjects/JesscarlettApp/dictapp.py", line 94, in <module>
     TestApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripplebehavior.py", line 245, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 969, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\PycharmProjects\JesscarlettApp\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
 NameError: name 'meaning' is not defined
```

This is my main.py and kv. (please ignore those additional unused modules.)
The issue is of this line "meaning.text = app.show_data_meaning()" in the kv. But I just don't know how to fix it. Many thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class WordScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MeaningScreen(Screen):
    pass


screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    
    WordScreen:
    MeaningScreen:

<WordScreen>
    name: 'wordscreen'
    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Word"
        id: text_field
        text:'default'
        icon_right: "dictionary"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.9}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'search'
        id: search_button
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
        on_release: 
            meaning.text = app.show_data_meaning()
            root.manager.current = 'meaningscreen'
            
<MeaningScreen>
    name: 'meaningscreen'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'wordscreen' 
    MDLabel:
        text: "Default"
        id: meaning
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
        font_style: 'Body1'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6} 

"""

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Dictionary App"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return sm

    def show_data_meaning(self):
        searchword = self.root.get_screen("wordscreen").ids.text_field.text
        print(searchword)
        dictionary = PyDictionary(searchword)
        meaning = dictionary.getMeanings()
        print(meaning)
        return meaning


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new method in your `TestApp` to set the text on the next screen

example:

```
    def my_func(self):
        self.root.get_screen("meaningscreen").ids.meaning.text = str(self.show_data_meaning())
```

and call your method in button release

```
on_release: 
        app.my_func()
        root.manager.current = 'meaningscreen'
```

you can also do this in kv file as well, you just need to get meaningscreen
then `meaningscreen.ids.text_field.meaning.text = app.show_data_meaning()`

here is your code after changes

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class WordScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MeaningScreen(Screen):
    pass


screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    WordScreen:
    MeaningScreen:

<WordScreen>
    name: 'wordscreen'
    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Word"
        id: text_field
        text:'default'
        icon_right: "dictionary"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.9}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'search'
        id: search_button
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
        on_release: 
            app.my_func()
            root.manager.current = 'meaningscreen'

<MeaningScreen>
    name: 'meaningscreen'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'wordscreen' 
    MDLabel:
        text: "Default"
        id: meaning
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
        font_style: 'Body1'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6} 

"""


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Dictionary App"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return sm

    def show_data_meaning(self):
        searchword = self.root.get_screen("wordscreen").ids.text_field.text
        print(searchword)
        dictionary = PyDictionary(searchword)
        meaning = dictionary.getMeanings()
        print(meaning)
        return meaning

    def my_func(self):
        self.root.get_screen("meaningscreen").ids.meaning.text = str(self.show_data_meaning())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Many thanks! It worked! The fact that I referenced meaning.text in the KV caused issue as it didn't know to go to meaningscreen. Creating a method that with 'self.root.get_screen("meaningscreen").ids.' helps it to find the id. Fantastic! A dumb question, in the str(self.show_data_meaning()), why used 'self.' instead of 'app.'?

Comment: I used self, cause I called the function in app class, so self refers to app, you can't use the app, root anywhere in python, you can only use app and root in kv language.